# Remove small dot above "i" in small caps font

Tags: fontspec

I would like to use Apple's SF Pro Display font in one of my documents, but it creates a rather displeasing small-cap letter "i" with a dot on top.

In Apple's SF Pro Rounded font, this does not occur. Furthermore, one font can generate an emdash, while the other can't.

Find an MWE below:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{fontspec} 

\setmainfont{SF Pro Display}

\begin{document}

{\small\textsc{\MakeLowercase{20:27 --- Ingo:}}} \\

{\small\textsc{\MakeLowercase{\fontspec{SF Pro Rounded}20:27 --- Ingo }}}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image: i above small caps]

Is there anything I can do to harmonize this, i.e. remove the dot above the i, and use an emdash consistently?

---

Here are some more variations of the problem:

```
{\small\textsc{\MakeLowercase{20:27 --- Ingo }}}

{\small\textsc{\MakeLowercase{20:27 --- ingo }}}

{\small\textsc{\MakeLowercase{20:27 --- \i ngo }}}

{\small\textsc{\MakeLowercase{20:27 --- ı ngo }}}
```

[image]

Comment: `\MakeLowercase{\fontspec{SF Pro Rounded}` is `\MakeLowercase{\fontspec{sf pro rounded}`which may work by accident, you probably should just lowercase the text

Comment: what happens if you replace the i by `\i`  or  `ı` dotless i

Comment: Thanks for the questions, I have added a few more exaples.

Comment: so the last one works except you added a space after the i

Comment: Afraid not really, if you pay close attention, the letter i somewhat too short. Same as in the row above (third from the top).

Comment: yes noticed after, you could clip the i if the font doesn't have the glyph

Comment: The fourth example, with lowercase dotlessi, might be useful. First, as already noted, you do not need a space after it. I see that the dotlessi is not only shorter than the other letters, it is less heavy. Try using `fontspec` technology to up-scale that letter by a small amount, to make it slightly taller (and slightly heavier). I believe that `\addfontfeature{ScaleAgain=value}` will help.

Comment: I can't reproduce it using LuaLaTeX (the font is not found with XeLaTeX).

Comment: This would be correct in Turkish, but not other languages. Which version of the font do you have? Does it support the `Language=` OpenType feature?

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce the “dotted I” problem after downloading and installing SF Pro.

The em-dash is produced regularly with both Display and Rounded; however, in the latter font the glyph is wider.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{fontspec} 

\setmainfont{SF Pro Display}
\newfontfamily{\sfprorounded}{SF Pro Rounded}[Ligatures=TeX]

\begin{document}

^^^^2014 (Display)

{\sfprorounded ^^^^2014} (Rounded)

\textsc{\MakeLowercase{20:27 --- Ingo:}}

\textsc{\MakeLowercase{\sfprorounded 20:27 --- Ingo:}}

\textsc{\MakeLowercase{20:27 --- Ingo}}

\textsc{\MakeLowercase{20:27 --- ingo}}

\textsc{\MakeLowercase{20:27 --- \i ngo}}

\textsc{\MakeLowercase{20:27 --- ıngo}}

\end{document}
```

The only changes I made to your code are:

1. I removed the `\fontspec` declaration inside `\MakeLowercase` (which is wrong), replacing it with the proper set of commands, that is, defining a font family;
2. I removed the space after `ı` in the last example
3. I removed the `\small` declarations and did nothing to possibly affect the issue.

[image]

As you see, calling the character as itself, U+2014, produces different glyphs in the two fonts. But nowhere I get the dotted i.